# force a character's format to UTF-16

Tags: php, unicode, utf-16

So, if I have a quasi-unicode UTF-16 character code of

```
0x14e
0xf6
```

How would I make sure that it's strict and adheres to the standard?

```
0x014E
0x00F6
```

I realize that I can do a few string manipulations, but I can't seem to find a built-in method with PHP...

Comment: 0x14e and 0x014E is exactly the same thing. The question is - where is it stored?

Comment: It's coming out of an XML file. I'm using it with chr(hexdec($number)) to convert it to the actual character, then passing it into imagefttext to create a PNG. It seemingly doesn't work right without being the full 6 digits.

Comment: That's because chr can only deal with ascii.. Use hex2bin instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate using mb_detect_encoding().
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php